# What is different RGBD SLAM VS RTAB-Map SLAM?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, 3d-slam, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

ROS beginners. So I'm not sure.

I tried to use rtabmap for slam using rgb-d in ROS slam.

But is rgbd_slam also provided in the ros package?

i can check the rgbslam at the following link.

http://wiki.ros.org/rgbdslam

Is this a package that can be used with gmapping, Cartographer, or RTAB-Map?

I would appreciate it if you let me know.

If RGBD slam is also available, I use rgb-d and 2d lidar sensors. Which is better, rgb-dlsam or RTAB-Mapslam?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348524/what-is-different-rgbd-slam-vs-rtab-map-slam?/) by [mywjdp@naver.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/52779/mywjdp@naver.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2020-04-06

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[RGBDSLAM](https://felixendres.github.io/rgbdslam_v2/) is a full SLAM approach like [GMapping](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping), [Cartographer](https://github.com/cartographer-project/cartographer) or [RTAB-Map](http://introlab.github.io/rtabmap/). There are many others compatible with ROS too. I will refer you to table 1 of this [paper](https://introlab.3it.usherbrooke.ca/mediawiki-introlab/images/7/7a/Labbe18JFR_preprint.pdf), which does a brief comparison of all available open-source SLAM approaches that can be used in ROS. Here is a copy of that table:
[image: image description]

As you can see, depending on the sensors you are using, you would use either a vision-based (RGBD-SLAM) or lidar-based (GMapping, Cartographer) approaches. Currently, only RTAB-Map can use both sensors at the same time. In your case, you won't be able to use the lidar with RGBDSLAM, which uses only RGB-D camera as input. In the same way, you cannot use *optimally* a RGB-D sensor with GMapping and Cartographer approaches (it is possible to use the depth projection in those approaches but they are more tuned for long-range lidar with large field of view). RGBDSLAM doesn't create a 2D map by default, but a 3D OctoMap. RTAB-Map can use RGB-D camera for loop closure detection, and lidar for 2D mapping. See this [configuration example](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot#Kinect_.2B-_Odometry_.2B-_2D_laser):
[image description http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=setupA.png](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=setupA.png)

In some applications, you could use only a lidar, so GMapping and Cartographer can be other good options.

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2020-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mywjdp@naver.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/52779/mywjdp@naver.com/) on 2020-04-06**:
Dear Mathieu

That is the perfect answer.

It's best. ^^

Have a nice day.

**Comment by [Asan A.](https://answers.ros.org/users/74365/asan-a./) on 2021-05-31**:
here is an additional paper for indoor slam overview
[Comparison of Various SLAM Systems for Mobile Robot in an Indoor Environment](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/328007381_Comparison_of_Various_SLAM_Systems_for_Mobile_Robot_in_an_Indoor_Environment)